# Using a string in a while statement

Tags: python, while-loop

How do you keep this from repeating "try again" when giving a wrong input:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print("Hello, World!")

name = input("What is your name?")

hobby = input("Cool, so " + name + " what do you do you for fun? You can say something like play, work, learn, etc.")

actions = {'play': 'awesome', 'work': 'must be busy', 'learn': 'ha, me too', }

while True:
    try:
        print(actions[hobby])
        break
    except KeyError:
        print("Try again.")
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. You explained what you do not want to do: what exactly do you want your code to do?

Comment: Start by asking for the input **in the loop**. `hobby` won't change so the `actions[hobby]` expression will forever throw the same exception.

Comment: Never mind I got it. I just had move the "while True:" above the hobby input